# How to compare between 3 different values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fb92c5d256cb4fd463f0944"
  },
  "ppCode": "A0007",
  "ppName": "ANGULLIA PARK OFF STREET",
  "parkingSystem": "Electronic Parking System",
  "vehCat": "Car",
  "availableLot": 210,
  "parkCapacity": 268,
  "startTime": 700,
  "endTime": 1100,
  "rates": [
    {
      "weekdayMin": 30,
      "weekdayRate": 1.3,
      "satdayMin": 30,
      "satdayRate": 1.3,
      "sunPHMin": 30,
      "sunPHRate": 0.7
    }
  ],
  "modified": "2333"
}, {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fb92c65256cb4fd463f0ac3"
  },
  "ppCode": "Y0019",
  "ppName": "YAN KIT ROAD / CANTONMENT ROAD OFF ST",
  "parkingSystem": "Electronic Parking System",
  "vehCat": "Motorcycle",
  "availableLot": 0,
  "parkCapacity": 8,
  "startTime": 2230,
  "endTime": 700,
  "rates": [
    {
      "weekdayMin": 510,
      "weekdayRate": 0.65,
      "satdayMin": 510,
      "satdayRate": 0.65,
      "sunPHMin": 510,
      "sunPHRate": 0.65
    }
  ],
  "modified": "2333"
}]
```

My current MongoDB structure. With the use of live updates every 5 mins to update availableLot and modified. I am trying to show document which startTime < modified < endTime. I have tried $where function but could not get the data I want to filter by.

Anyone can help out?

Comment: Is there are reason `startTime` / `endTime` are numbers and `modified` is a string?

Comment: StartTime and EndTime are related for the pricing during this timing. Modified is when was the API called to modify the availableLot, which is every 5mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aggregation query with a `$project` stage to determine if the values are between the start and end times, and then filter on only those where both are true. Note this example assumes `$modified` is a numeric (if it isn't, convert it first):

```
result = db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            'start': {'$gte': ['$modified', '$startTime']},
            'end': {'$gte': ['$endTime', '$modified']}
        }
    },
    {
        '$match': {'start': True, 'end': True}
    }
])
```